# Convergence in distribution of maximum of exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, exponential-distribution

I have to solve the following homework problem:

> Let $X_{1}, \ldots ,X_{n}$ be i.i.d. random variables with $X_{1}\sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and let $X$ have distribution function $F(x)=1-e^{-e^{-x}}$. Show that $\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_{k} - \log(n)$ converges to $X$ in distribution.

What I have done so far: 
We can compute that
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_{k} \leq x\Big)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq x)^{n}=(1-e^{-x})^{n}.$$
Substituting $x+\log(n)$ for $x$, it follows that

$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_{k} \leq x + \log(n)\Big)= \big(1-e^{-x-\log(n)}\big)^{n}.$$

This does not converge to $1-e^{-e^{-x}}$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Isn‘t it $(1-e^{-x})$?

Comment: Oh man, sorry for the typo. The problem says that $X_{1}\sim\text{Exp}(1)$. So, my calculation is correct, I think.

Comment: Yes, but the cdf converges to $\exp(-e^{-x})$.

Comment: Okay. Then, I think, the definition of $F$ in the problem must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $1-\exp(-e^{-x})$ as is not a distribution function (check the limit at $\infty$ for example). But $F(x)=\exp(-e^{-x})$ *is* a valid distribution function (of the [Gumbel/Extreme-value distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution)).

You should say that $\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\le k\le n} X_k -\log n\le x\right)\longrightarrow \exp(-e^{-x})$ for all real $x$ as $n\to \infty$. Hence the convergence in distribution.